# K&R - Section 1.9 - Character Arrays (concerning the getline function)

Tags: c, arrays

My question is concerning some code from section 1.9-character arrays in the Kernighan and Ritchie book. The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000 /* maximum input line size */

int getline(char line[], int maxline);
void copy(char to[], char from[]);

/* print longest input line */
main()
{
    int len;        /* current line length */
    int max;        /* maximum length seen so far */
    char line[MAXLINE];     /* current input line */
    char longest[MAXLINE];  /* longest line saved here */

    max = 0;
    while ((len = getline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0)
        if (len > max) {
            max = len;
            copy(longest, line);
        }
    if (max > 0) /* there was a line */
        printf("%s", longest);
    return 0;
}

/* get line: read a line into s, return length */
int getline(char s[], int lim) // 
{
    int c, i;

    for (i=0; i<lim-1 && ((c=getchar()) != EOF) && c != '\n' ; ++i) 
        s[i] = c; 
    if (c == '\n') {
        s[i] = c; 
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0'; 
    return i;
}

/* copy : copy 'from' into 'to'; assume to is big enough */
void copy(char to[], char from[])
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while ((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0')
        ++i;
}
```

My question is about the getline function.  Now looking at this following output from my command line as a reference:

```
me@laptop
$ characterarray.exe
aaaaa
a
aaaaaa
^Z
aaaaaa

me@laptop
$
```

When I type in the first character which is 'a', does the character 'a' go through the for loop, in the getline function, and initialize s[0] - s[998] = a ? And my second part of the question is once the program leaves the for loop and goes to the

```
s[i] = '\0'
return i;
```

wouldn't it be initialized s[998] = '\0' and the return integer is 998?  I've spent over an hour staring at this problem and I can't seem to grasp what is going on.

Comment: `main()` should better be `int main(void)`.

Comment: @SouravGhosh are there still compilers that care?

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev AFAIK, its the standard (and personally, I prefer to play by the rules).:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Character 'a' does not go through the `for` loop. Look here:

```
for (i=0; i<lim-1 && ((c=getchar()) != EOF) && c != '\n' ; ++i)
```

`c = getchar()` is where your program stops and waits for user input -- not just once, but in a loop! This is a condition of continuing the `for` loop, and each time it is checked, a `getchar()` is called. The loop goes only one char at a time. Each time a char is added to the current end of an array (indicated by `i`) and the loop breaks when a newline symbol is entered or when a limit size is reached. This is very compact code but it is kind of oldschool C coding which is not very readable these relaxed days. It can be broken into following parts:

```
i = 0;
while(i < lim - 1) {
    c = getchar();
    if (c == EOF || c == '\n') break;
    s[i] = c;
    ++i;
}
s[i] = '\0'; 
return i;
```

(also I don't think a newline symbol is needed to be included in the string, so I omitted the

```
if (c == '\n') {
    s[i] = c; 
    ++i;
}
```

part.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how the input is working in the for-loop.

Before the for-loop, the array `s` is empty(ish. It's full of whatever garbage is in that memory). If you type in a single `a` and hit enter, the for-loop goes through 2 characters `'a'` and `'\n'`. For `'a'`, the variable `c` becomes `'a'` from getchar() in the for-loop parameters, and that gets saved in the `i` spot (which is 0) of `s`. So, the array `s` is now 
`s[0] = 'a'` and the rest of `s` has random garbage in it.

Then `c` becomes `'\n'` from getchar(). This stops the for-loop because of the `c != '\n'` check. The if-statement has `s[i]`, where `i` is 1, become `'\n'` and `i` bumps up to 2.

Now `s` is

`s[0] = 'a'
s[1] = '\n'`

`getline` finishes up by making `s[2]` be `'\0'`, which is the end of string character, and returns `i`.

Your end result is

`s[0] = 'a'
s[1] = '\n'
s[2] = '\0'`

and `i`, your length, is 2.